# How to get system music queue from MusicKit?

Tags: ios, swift, queue, apple-musickit

I'm using MusicKit to build an iOS app that manages the queue of Apple Music. I am able to get the current item in the queue by:

```
SystemMusicPlayer.shared.queue.currentEntry
```

And I can subscribe to changes in the queue with:

```
cancellable = SystemMusicPlayer.shared.queue.objectWillChange.sink(receiveValue: { _ in
    print("Received value: \(SystemMusicPlayer.shared.queue.currentEntry)")
})
```

However, I'm unable to figure out how I can get the upcoming items in the queue. Does anyone know how to do this with the new MusicKit API?

Answer (score 0):

Apple has its own forums where developers can ask questions about MusicKit and get answers from Apple employees who are familiar with the framework.

I would recommend that you check the [MusicKit section of the Apple Developer  Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/tags/musickit), and post your question there.

I hope it helps.

Best regards,

Comment: This guy is actually the apple dev working on musickit..